# how can I display a text flowing out over the top of other text clearly

Tags: css, ellipsis

I want a long file to flow out over the top of other texts when it is clicked.

The line looks like this. 
   part1 part1 part1 part1...       part2 part2 part2

When I click the ellipsis, I want part1s to flow out over part2s, not overlapping, so part1s are clearly readable. How can I do that?

In css,

```
.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;             
  text-overflow: ellipsis;   
}
.ellipsis:hover {
  text-overflow: initial;
  overflow: visible;
}

<div class="col-xs-5 ellipsis">part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1</div>
<div class="col-xs-5">part2 part2 part2 </div>
```

The current rendering is as follows:

[image]

I'd like to flow the part1 over the top of the part2 clearly.

[image]

Comment: can you do a mock up image of what you want the result to look like, it's not very clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A long file name flowing out over other texts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39443948/a-long-file-name-flowing-out-over-other-texts)