# A long file name flowing out over other texts

Tags: html, css

I want a long file to flow out over the top of other texts when it is clicked.

The line looks like this. 
   part1 part1 part1 part1...       part2 part2 part2

When I click the ellipsis, I want part1s to flow out over part2s, not overlapping, so part1s are clearly readable. How can I do that?

In css,

```
.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;             
  text-overflow: ellipsis;   
}
.ellipsis:hover {
  text-overflow: initial;
  overflow: visible;
}

<div class="col-xs-5 ellipsis">part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1</div>
<div class="col-xs-5">part2 part2 part2 </div>
```

The current rendering is as follows:

[image]

I'd like to flow the part1 over the top of the part2 clearly.

[image]

Comment: Give the flown-out part1 a background?

Comment: The background color to white is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `white-space` property if you want to play with `text-overflow` as:

### Code Snippet

```css
.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.ellipsis:hover {
  text-overflow: initial;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-5 ellipsis">part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1 part1</div>
<div class="col-xs-5">part2 part2 part2</div>
```

Comment: The normal white space works on hovering but it renders to next lines, i.e. wrapping, not in one line spreading out over other texts.

Answer (score 0):

My method doesn't use bootstrap, however you could always just wrap it up in a `col-xs-12` or as desired.

Also, you said on click you want this to happen, and since you are using bootstrap, I included a jquery click function as well.

```js
$(".cont p").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.cont p{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 5em;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
 }

.cont p.active{
  max-width: none;
  text-overflow: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cont">
  <p>hello hello hello hello hello hello</p>
  <p><b>hello</b></p>
</div>
```